# Polymorphism Trouble C#

Tags: c#, polymorphism

Im trying to make something like an Rpg game atm but im really stuck on something i really dont know what to do anymore i really need help it might look like a noob question but please try to answer me >.< this is the parent class

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Personaje
    {
        public Rango Damage;
        public int Defensa;

        public int HP;

        public int MP;
        public bool Evade;
        public bool Counter;
        public string Nombre;
        public Personaje() { }
        public Personaje(Rango Damage, int Defensa, int HP, bool Evade, bool Counter, string Nombre)
        {
            this.Damage = Damage;
            this.Defensa = Defensa;
            this.HP = HP;
            this.Evade = Evade;
            this.Counter = Counter;
            this.Nombre = Nombre;
        }
    }
}
```

this is one of the childs

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Enemigo:Personaje
    {

    }
}
```

this is one of the childs and the one im having trouble with i dont know how to put the status on it

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Poring:Enemigo
    {
        int HP = 30;
        int MP = 10;
        int Def = 0;
        public bool Evade()
        {
            return false;
        }
        public bool Counter()
        {
            return false;
        }
        public Rango Damage()
        {
            Rango r = new Rango();
            r.min = 10;
            r.max = 15;
            return r;
        }
        string Nombre = "Poring";

        //Personaje Propiedades = new Personaje(Damage,Def, HP, Evade, Counter, Nombre);
        Personaje omg = new Personaje();


    }
}
```

Comment: As a tip, you'll probably get better answers if you make it clearer what you're having difficulty with --   "I don't know how to put the status" is a bit imprecise.  (I thought it was your Evade and Counter methods, but lfoust thinks, and he's probably right, that you're asking about setting those initial property values via the constructor.)  I know it's hard for a beginner to know the terminology but being as specific as you can always helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you are wanting to be able to call the constructor on the parent to pass in the state of the object. You have to overload the constructor at each level of the class heirarchy.

```
class Enemigo : Personaje
{
    public Enemigo(Rango Damage, int Defensa, int HP, bool Evade, bool Counter, string Nombre)
       : base(Damage, Defensa, HP, Evade, Counter, Nombre)
    {
    }
}

class Poring:Enemigo
{
       public Poring(Rango Damage, int Defensa, int HP, bool Evade, bool Counter, string Nombre)
          : base(Damage, Defensa, HP, Evade, Counter, Nombre)
          {
          }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ,yeah im sorry if i wasnt precise but yeah i meant the starting values for each character,thank you very much that was really fast btw xD

Answer (score 1):

In your base class, you have declared Evade and Counter as public fields.  To override them, you need to make these properties or methods (methods in this case), and mark them `virtual` or `abstract` in the base class, and `override` in the derived class.  If you want them to be abstract (i.e. the base class has no "default" implementation, and derived classes **must** override them to provide an implementation), you must make the base class abstract too:

```
public abstract class Personaje
{
  public abstract bool Evade();
}

public class Poring : Enemigo
{
  public override bool Evade()
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```